# Cannot individual add digits of number together in vba

Tags: vba, addition

I want to be able to add together the individual digits of a 4 digit number, but it does not seem to work.
I am doing this purely in VBA code. The result is output to a worksheet.
I have extracted part of my code and put it into a separate macro to test it and still get the same result. It concatenates the digits together.
I have added in lots of msgbox lines to see what it is doing, but cannot work out why, in this case, the value of main is not added up into the intm variable.
The variables intd1 to intd4 get the values correctly, but when I try to add them together into intm, it just concatenates them together.

```
Sub AddDigits()
'
' Add individual digits of number together
'
Dim intd1, intd2, intd3, intd4, main, intm As Integer

main = 1234
    intd1 = Left(main, 1)
MsgBox (intd1)
    intd2 = Mid(main, 2, 1)
MsgBox (intd2)
    intd3 = Mid(main, 3, 1)
MsgBox (intd3)
    intd4 = Right(main, 1)
MsgBox (intd4)
    intm = intd1 + intd2 + intd3 + intd4
MsgBox ("intm = " & intm & Chr(13) & _
        "intd1 = " & intd1 & Chr(13) & _
        "intd2 = " & intd2 & Chr(13) & _
        "intd3 = " & intd3 & Chr(13) & _
        "intd4 = " & intd4 & Chr(13))
End Sub
```

Comment: This is why we preach "One Dim per line" in VBA land.

Comment: `intm = Application.Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(" & main & ",ROW(1:4),1)))")`

Answer (score 2):

When you declare the variables the way you did, the first bit are all "variants", and VBA your use of Mid, Left, and Right are all string functions, so VBA coverts the variant to Strings:

[image]

If you dim your variables properly, you get the expected result:

```
Sub AddDigits()
'
' Add individual digits of number together
'
Dim intd1 As Integer, _
    intd2 As Integer, _
    intd3 As Integer, _
    intd4 As Integer, _
    main As Integer, _
    intm As Integer

main = 1234
    intd1 = Left(main, 1)
MsgBox (intd1)
    intd2 = Mid(main, 2, 1)
MsgBox (intd2)
    intd3 = Mid(main, 3, 1)
MsgBox (intd3)
    intd4 = Right(main, 1)
MsgBox (intd4)
    intm = intd1 + intd2 + intd3 + intd4
MsgBox ("intm = " & intm & Chr(13) & _
        "intd1 = " & intd1 & Chr(13) & _
        "intd2 = " & intd2 & Chr(13) & _
        "intd3 = " & intd3 & Chr(13) & _
        "intd4 = " & intd4 & Chr(13))
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. You are a star. I do not understand why declaring variables on one line is different to declaring each one separately though? I thought concise coding was better.

Comment: @StephenePrivate Glad to help!  It's just the way Microsoft designed it...in VBA you have to declare each one separately, no way around it (unless you cast the value in the code, which isn't ideal).  Just one of those things you'll have to live with when working in VBA. It's not so bad once you get used to it.  Good luck with the rest of your project!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer, you can also convert the data type anywhere later in the code. To convert anything to int use Cint. Similarly for other type conversion you check the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions)

```
 intm = CInt(intd1) + CInt(intd2) + CInt(intd3) + CInt(intd4)
```